# How to add an Id, value and onclick event to a dynamic generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have to add onglets (dev) and affect them an id, value and onclick.
i tried by this way but is not working

```
function functionDeleteLevel(s1,s2){
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("valeur", "deleteLevel");
  ajaxPost("/deleteLevel", formData, function (reponse) {
    var data = JSON.parse(reponse);
    data.forEach(function(level){
      var newLi = document.createElement("li");
      newLi.value = level.level;
      newLi.id = "levelId_"+level.level;
      newLi.innerHTML = 'onclick="functionSelectedLevel(this.id)"';
      newLi.innerHTML = '<a data-toggle="tab">Niveau'+level.level+'</a>';
      s2.appendChild(newLi);
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: i change newLi.innerHTML = 'onclick="functionSelectedLevel(this.id)"';  by this line newLi.addEventListener('click', function() {functionSelectedLevel(this.id);})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
newLi.addEventListener('click', function() {functionSelectedLevel(this.id);})
```

or

```
newLi.onclick = function() {functionSelectedLevel(this.id);};
```

or - with a bit of a change to `functionSelectedLevel`

```
newLi.addEventListener('click', functionSelectedLevel)
```

or

```
newLi.onclick = functionSelectedLevel;
```

functionSelectedLevel would then be

```
functionSelectedLevel() {
    // here, the value of this is the element that was clicked
    do things with this.id
}
```